# Mardown - Rich Text - Strapi - Nuxt 3 - display on website

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown, strapi, richtext, nuxt3

POST FOR BLOG.

I fetch rich text from API for example:

{

"description":"###Title. **font bold** ###Secound Title..."

}

I want convert description to html structure. How can i do it?

I tried use to content nuxt 3 but i need files md.

I would like only convert the description to html structure...

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

vue3-markdown-it solves this problem.

[Rendered example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLnEz.png)

https://dev.to/matijanovosel/rendering-markdown-in-vue-3-3maj

https://github.com/JanGuillermo/vue3-markdown-it